# Probability problem about calls to a fire department

Tags: probability, statistics

In a particular city, the probability a call to a fire department concerns various situations is as given below:

1. fire in a detached home: $p_1=0.10$
2. fire in a semi-detached home: $p_2=0.05$
3. fire in an apartment or multiple unit residence: $p_3=0.05$
4. fire in a non-residential building: $p_4=0.15$
5. non-fire-related emergency: $p_5=0.15$
6. false alarm: $p_6=0.50$

(a) Give the joint probability function for $X_1,\dots,X_6$ (I know how to do this one...)

(b) What is the probability that there is at least one apartment fire, given that there are 4 fire-related calls? (cannot come up with a formula for this one)

Comment: Try this: in 100 calls, how many are fire-related, and how many of those are **apartment** fire calls?

So what is the probability of non-apartment fire call?  Of four of them?  And what's the complement of "none"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On average, in 100 calls there will be 50 false alarms and 15 non-fire-related calls.

So there will be only 35 fire related calls, of which 5 will be apartment calls.  So the probability that a fire call will be an apartment call is $\frac{1}{7}$

The probability that a fire call will **not** be apartment related is $\frac{6}{7}$

The probability of **four** non-apartment fire calls is $(\frac{6}{7})^4$

So the probability of **at least** one apartment call in four fire calls is:$$1-(\frac{6}{7})^4$$ or  $  0.460225$